# What is the big O notation for this algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity

What is the big O notation for this algorithm?

```
i<-0
k<-0
while (i<=n)
{
  for (j<-i to n**2)
   {
       k<-k+1
   }
   i<-i*2
 }
```

Possible Answers:

a. O(logn)

b. O(n)

c. O(nlogn)

d. None of the answers

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: The running time depends on many things that you don't specify, so the question can't be answered.

Comment: @ScottHunter i just want to accent .

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the question was in exam , and its looks only like this.

Comment: Then the right response is not to answer but to reject the question. Simple as that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt if you know the answer whats the problem to answer ?
why you do a difficult life

Comment: I hereby claim that the answer is 42. Proof me wrong. Seriously, don't you see that the very question doesn't make sense? Do you also want me to guess the right question? Oh, and by the way, this smells like homework and you have shown zero effort to solve it. That is the reason for me not to give you solutions and others here agree. Helping people do their homework is okay, but doing it for them isn't.

Comment: @MawasiKareem - perhaps the question was asking what the big O notation for this algorithm is? The actual execution time will differ based on various things.

Comment: @Jake
this is a question from emax , there are was 4 answers
a.o(logn)
b.o(n)
c.o(nlogn)
d.None of the answers

Comment: @MawasiKareem - those are all big O notation answers, not execution time

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i think i does asked the question in a wrong way ,I apologise about that

Comment: @Jake i understand , i asked the question in a wrong way and iam sorry for that.

Comment: @MawasiKareem - also, are the answers uppercase o's (O(logn)) or lowercase o's (o(logn)). Lowercase is little o notation and uppercase is big o notation. it's more likely the question is big o, but wanted to check to make sure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As `i` is multiplied by `2` each time in a `while`, Hence the `while` loop will be run `log(n)` times. And inner `for` loop will be run in `O(n^2)` as `i` is at most `n`. Hence, the time complexity of the code in `O` notation is `O(n^2 log(n))`.